# JUnit global before/after

Tags: junit, junit-runner

I need some way to execute code before/after each test. This code should be the same for all tests and test cases globally. I was hoping I could use RunListener, but it seems that I need to alter all the tests (or their parent class) to specify custom test runner or use JUnitCore for it to work.

Is there any way I can register this listener without affecting the code base? (there are many many tests and I would need to alter a lot of them for the listener to work)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use a JUnit Rule feature for it. I assume that all your tests extend some basic test class. So you could add the Rule there.

I think you'll need to implement a custom rule. Quick googling reveals a pretty good [tutorial](http://carlosbecker.com/posts/junit-rules).